# Transfer from Heisenberg to Ising model

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-spin, hamiltonian, ising-model

It is well know, that ferromagnets can be described using Hamiltonian
$$
    H = -\sum\limits_{i<j}J_{ij}\, (\mathbf{s}_i \cdot \mathbf{s}_j).
$$
where (three dimensional) spins $\mathbf{s}_i$ corresponds to magnetic moments $\boldsymbol{\mu}_i$ of atoms which are usually placed in sites of lattice. One can treat them as spin operators $\hat{\mathbf{s}}_i$ and obtain [*Heisenberg model*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_model_(quantum)). Or one can just let spins to take values $\mathbf{s}_i = s_i\mathbf{e}_i$, where $s_i = \pm 1$ which corresponds to  spin $s=\frac12$, and $\mathbf{e}_i$ are fixed for each atom *Ising axes*. Them one will come up with *Ising model*.

Second approach, for example, is successfully used in [that article](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v451/n7174/abs/nature06433.html) to describe spin ice.

So it is clear that Ising model is simplified Heisenberg model. And my question is **why is this simplification legitimate?**

As it was once mentioned to me this reduction can be explained the following way. Actually crystalline lattice has some (local) direction $\mathbf{e}_i$ such that, roughly speaking, to interaction between spins also contributes such factor as
$$
    H = -\sum\limits_{i<j}J_{ij}\, (\mathbf{s}_i \cdot \mathbf{s}_j) - D\sum\limits_{i} (\mathbf{e}_i \cdot \mathbf{s}_i)^2.
$$
And if $D \gg J_{ij}$ then one can obviously disregard all states but $|m=\pm s\rangle$ when calculates the partition function.

Anyhow, there must be some transition from spin--operators description to Ising--like. So **are there any related physical phenomena?** Some transitions that occur at temperatures $T \gg T_c$?

P.S. I'm actually interested in such values of $D$ for Dysprosium and Holmium from the article mentioned above. They have $J\sim T_c\sim 1 K$.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that the Ising model isn't just a simplification of the Heisenberg model. Ising breaks a discrete symmetry (namely $Z_2$ symmetry) while Heisenberg breaks a continuous one ($O(3)$). They thus describe different physics.

Comment: Thanks, @Dimitri. I'm confused about your usage of word "break", but if I get you right, you're talking abou so-called _Classical Heisenberg model_. And I meant _Quantum Heisenberg model_ which Hamiltanian is invarian only under spins swaping. And I'm considering some, that I belive one could call 3D Ising model (see link to the article in post). And you're talking about 1D Ising model, that is not the case (it doesn't differ from 1D Heisenberg model, if one would ever consider such, at all).

Comment: You are right, I was indeed talking about the classical Heisenberg model. In your case, I believe you could call it a 3D Ising model as you have no exterior magnetic field (for it to be called Ising you need the magnetic field to be in the same direction as the Ising axis).